# Where is python interpreter located in virtualenv?

Tags: python, linux

### Where is python intrepreter located in virtual environment ?

I am making a GUI project and I stuck while finding the python interpreter in my virtual environment.

[image: where is python interpreter located in virtual env ?]

Comment: If it's not located there automatically, if you type it in once, it will probably show up again the next time. Current answers tell you what you need to type in.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Execute next code and it will print location of your python interpreter.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: @VedantNandwana Enable what? You mean how to activate virtual env and use it in VSCode?

Comment: @VedantNandwana To use virtual env under VSCode you probably just change dir to this virtual env's folder inside your console and type `code .`, hit enter.

Answer (score 4):

To a lot of extents, it depends on how the virtual environment was created. If you installed like this `py -m venv env` then you would find it here `.\env\Scripts\activate`  . How ever if you created the environment using conda then you would find it here `Anaconda_installation_folder/envs/name_of_environment`. SO brief answer to your question, you would find it withing you env folder.

Comment: do you mean to say you want to activate the environment ? or rather lauch python interpreter in that environment ?

Comment: I had enabled it in terminal (bash) , but I'm unable to enable it in vscode

Comment: VS code by default, the Python extension looks for and uses the first Python interpreter it finds in the system path. To select a specific environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P). The Python: Select Interpreter command displays a list of available global environments, conda environments, and virtual environments. You can select from here. I routinely use this feature.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, I would appreciate it if you could mark this answer accepted.

Comment: Thanks Bhartah :) Edit : I was struggling in this from 2 days .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically active virtual env or (venv). Try this.

Install virtual env

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

If you already have venv present. you can refer to this to get the executable python3 file like this.

#referred @Arty answer above.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

this will print the python3 path of that venv.

later open the command pallet ( `ctrl + shift + P` ) and type `python` as shown in the image.

[image]

Then click on

[image]

and paste that path into the input box.

Now the setup is done.
Now every time you open a terminal, it will automatically open your terminal in the virtual env and will auto-run the virtual env for you