# "Unknown Configuration Setting" VSCode greyed Out

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have trouble configurating my settings.json in VSCode.
At first, I had my code opened as a workspace and it underlined general Python imports such as `from django.db import models` or `from django.core import serializers` or `import nltk`. The warning I got was "unresolved import". This happened for **all** basic Python / Django imports.

I realized that I didn't have an interpreter in my .venv folder, so then followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64173613/where-is-python-interpreter-located-in-virtualenv). I re-opened my code in Ubuntu with `. code` and now all personalized settings I have are greyed out:

settings.json:
[picture of greyed out settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Wap.png)

On hover, the warning I get is `Unknown Configuration Setting No quick fixes available`

How do I activate these settings again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the reason: the right Python extensions hadn't been installed.

There is an option to install the Python extension in Ubuntu WSL which is what I am working on. After installing this, the settings were known. :)